# Disallow special characters

Tags: c#, regex

Update:

i just realized that, how about dont allow any special characters instead of writing every single special character?

here is an example of what i am doing: `http://cnn.com/news/latest.html&id=1`  so strip only if `&` is at the begining or end.

Below code strips these (  `+,(,),;,"` ) special characters and it works fine

```
 static String StripSpcialChar(String param)
        {
            String result = null;
            if (param != null)
            {                
                Regex re = new Regex("\\&|\\(|\\)|\\<|\\>|\\\"|\\;|\n|\r|\\`");
                result = re.Replace(param, "");
                result = result.Trim();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

but my questions is, how can I strip `&` only if they have it at the beginning or end?

Comment: Match either `((?<=^)&)` or `(&(?=$))` would be my guess. -- **EDIT** Also, you can use the `@` prefix (literal) on strings and make your pattern a little more legible.

Comment: Or you could just use .EndsWith and .StartsWith method to check and then remove in order the last and first characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tested and working**. Use this expression:

```
Regex re = new Regex("\\(|\\)|\\<|\\>|\\\"|\\;|\n|\r|\\`|^&|&$");
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(StripSpcialChar("ali&")); // prints ali
Console.WriteLine(StripSpcialChar("&ali")); // prints ali
Console.WriteLine(StripSpcialChar("a&li")); // prints a&li
```

---

## NOTE

If you need to strip at the beginning or end of the **word**, try this:

```
Regex re = new Regex("\\(|\\)|\\<|\\>|\\\"|\\;|\n|\r|\\`|\b&|&\b");
```

Comment: i just realized that, how about dont allow any special characters instead of writing every single special character?

Answer (score 1):

```
"&this is a test&&&".Trim('&');
```

Comment: here is an example of what i am doing: `http://cnn.com/news/latest.html&id=1`  so strip only if `&` is at the begining or end.

Comment: @AbuHamzah: Now, given we're talking URLs here, what's the end-all goal of this? (Why are you striping special characters? I'm almost certain there's a better method available.)

Comment: @Brad: i have a page that validates url... so searching against db to see if the url is exists or not, and before i make a search on my db i want to strip any sepcial characters. hope this make sense.

Comment: @AbuHamzah: How are you connecting to the Database? Most database connectors have a sanitize method for just this purpose.

Comment: hmm i am not sure about db connectors have sanitize method will you show how is that work?, i am a regular db connection through ado.net

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Regex re = new Regex("(^&)|(&$)|\\(|\\)|\\<|\\>|\\\"|\\;|\n|\r|\\`");
```

Comment: It looks like this one does what he wants, which is strip ampersands at either the beginning or end or string, as well as strip special characters off

Comment: i just realized that, how about dont allow any special characters instead of writing every single special character?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
string newString = string.Trim(oldString, '&');
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex uses `^` to mean "beginning of string" and `$` for "end of string":
`"^&|&$"` 
should match a string starting-with or ending-in ampersand (&)